# Change button value Angular 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular6, angular7

One question:

```
<button (click)="activateMotion(1)">
    <img class="emotion-icon" id="positive-icon" src="" />
</button>
<button (click)="activateMotion(-1)">
    <img class="emotion-icon" id="negative-icon" src="" />
</button>
```

I have two buttons with the value is an image. I want to write a function call : activateMotion(). I want to change the image inside the button base on the value 1 or -1. I can use jQuery to achieve the goal here, but I am writing the app in Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also you a **template reference** to your image element and pass it in your function call, then set the `src` attribute:

```
<button (click)="activateMotion(1, img1)">
    <img #img1 class="emotion-icon" id="positive-icon" src="" />
</button>
<button (click)="activateMotion(-1, img2)">
    <img #img2 class="emotion-icon" id="negative-icon" src="" />
</button>
```

```
const src1 = '...';
const src2 = '...';

activateMotion(value: number, img: HTMLElement): void {
    if (value === 1) {
        img.setAttribute('src', src1);
    } else {
        img.setAttribute('src', src2)
    }
}
```

Or simpler, you change the src via input binding on the image:

```
<img [src]="..." />
```

Comment: Why not pass to the function a template reference variable that refers to the image? Also, the variable will refer to an `HTMLElement` (or a more specific type), not to an `ElementRef`, unlike when you use such a variable with `ViewChild`.

Comment: Well, you are absolutely right, I will modify my answer

Answer (score 6):

Your question is too broad, since you apparently haven't tried anything yet, but it'll look like this:

```
<button [innerHTML]="myComponentVariableName"></button>
```

Then, in your function, you'll conditionally render the image:

```
let myComponentVariableName = '';

if (something) {
    myComponentVariableName = '<img ... />';
} else {
    myComponentVariableName = '<img ... />';
}
```

You could also put the image in the markup and just change the source attribute.

```
<button><img [src]="myComponentVariableName" /></button>
```